# Avoid interference between multiple Matplotlib figures on the web

Tags: django, matplotlib

I have a page with multiple Matplotlib figures embedded. The figures get inserted/manipulated via Ajax as follows (with a time stamp in order to get reloaded by the browser):

```
<img src="/charts/somedata.png?time=' + str(time.time()) + '" />
```

The urls are then matched to a view like (I should mention that I use Django):

```
(r'^charts/(?P<chart>[A-Za-z_]+).png$', 'views.charts'),

def charts(request, chart):
    # Dynamically loading the appropriate module
    chart_module = import_module('functions.charts.' + chart)
    return chart_module.show_chart(request)
```

The chart modules (somedata.py) look like this:

```
from __future__ import division
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse

def show_chart(request):
    try:
        # Initiating figure
        from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
        from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
        fig1 = figure(figsize=(5.33,4), facecolor = 'white')
        ax = fig1.add_axes([0.02,0.02,0.98,0.98], aspect='equal')

        # Some plotting to ax

        canvas=FigureCanvas(fig1)
        response=HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
        canvas.print_png(response)
        fig1.clear()
        return response

    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

With matplotlib version 0.99.? I sometimes got the problem that part of one chart was drawn in another chart on the same page. Sometimes, that was fixed after a reload. The solution I came up with was to put the following in settings.py:

```
# Force matplotlib to NOT use any Xwindows backend.
# This is necessary before importing pyplot or anything else from matplotlib
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

However, after updating to matplotlib version 1.0.1, the problem is back. The figures interfere with each other, or parts of a figure are not drawn at all? Any ideas about where the problem could be?

EDIT: Example of two plots in one. The lines on top belong to another figure, where they are missing. I should also mention that this is never an issue running the development server locally!
[image: Oops: Something went wrong!]

Comment: Can you show us an example png with two plots drawn on it?

Comment: @jozzas Please see my edit above: This is rather annoying but gets often solved after a reload. Any ideas what that could depend on?

Comment: I would move your matplotlib import lines to the top of file, for a start. Also look at using [savefig](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) rather than print_png. savefig works on just a figure, whereas pring_png works on your canvas, which looks like it's being recycled and not cleared properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the matplotlib import lines from settings.py to the top of each chart module as well as using savefig (as proposed by jozzas - thanks) seems to have solved the interference problem:

This was done by removing:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
canvas=FigureCanvas(fig1)
canvas.print_png(response)
```

Then I added instead:

```
fig1.savefig(response, format='png')
```

**UPDATE:**
The main issue was that the pyplot function did not correctly attach to the figure instance, which was discussed and solved in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254379/how-can-i-attach-a-pyplot-function-to-a-figure-instance).