# Python Pylab subplot bug?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting some data using pylab and everything works perfect as I expect. I have 6 different graphs to plot and I can individually plot them in separate figures. But when I try to `subplot()` these graphs, the last one `(subplot(3,2,6))` doesn't show anything.

What confuses me is that this 6th graph is drawn perfectly when put in a separate figure but not in the subplot - with identical configurations.

Any ideas what may be causing the problem ?

Comment: I am glad you sorted out your own problem, however could you add some example code so this will be more helpful for future users.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that subplot() should be called before the plot(), issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you are working with more than one axes or writing non-interactive scripts it is better to use the OO interface, rather than the state-machine (MATLAB-like) interface.  You could do this as:

```
fig, sub_lst = plt.subplots(3, 2)
sub_lst = sub_lst.ravel() # flatten list
for sub_p in sub_lst:
    sub_p.plot(...)
    # what ever other plotting commands you use
```

Note that the plotting functions are member functions of the `axes` objects returned by `subplots`.

See [How can I attach a pyplot function to a figure instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254379/how-can-i-attach-a-pyplot-function-to-a-figure-instance/14261698#14261698) for a longer discussion of the OO vs state-machine interfaces