# Plot to Specific Axes in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I plot to a specific axes in matplotlib?  I created my own object which has its own plot method and takes standard args and kwargs to adjust line color, width, etc, I would also like to be able to plot to a specific axes too.

I see there is an axes property that accepts an Axes object but no matter what it still only plots to the last created axes.

Here is an example of what I want

```
fig, ax = subplots(2, 1)

s = my_object()
t = my_object()

s.plot(axes=ax[0])
t.plot(axes=ax[1])
```

Comment: I suggest you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254379/how-can-i-attach-a-pyplot-function-to-a-figure-instance/14261698#14261698

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I said in the comment, read 
[How can I attach a pyplot function to a figure instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254379/how-can-i-attach-a-pyplot-function-to-a-figure-instance/14261698#14261698) for an explanation of the difference between the OO and state-machine interfaces to `matplotlib`.

You should modify your plotting functions to be something like

```
def plot(..., ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        ax = gca()
    ax.plot(..., **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, thats pretty close to what I ended up doing. Can you tell me why there is an axes property though? Setting this property should associate the line artists with that axes according to the documentation, but I don't see that.

Comment: I think it is an artifact of the way that the documentation is generate, the `Line2D` object has an `axes` property, but it is set by the code in `plot` and the value you pass in is ignored.  Can you point me to where the documentation says it should have that behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the plot function of a specific axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import sin, cos
f, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y1 = sin(x)
y2 = cos(x)
plt.sca(ax[0])
plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.sca(ax[1])
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.show()
```

This should plot to the two different subplots.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that I can do that, but that won't work for my plot function within my class definition.  I guess I can manually look to see if a axes property is set, but I guess I'm confused as to why the plot function takes an axes property if its not to plot to that axes.

Comment: I have edited the example to use the function `sca()` which sets the currenty active axes. It should work now with the normal plot function, so that you can use that one in your class.

Comment: How does the plot function of your class work? For me your example works fine for the plot command of `matplotlib.pyplot`. The plot is made in the specified axes.

Comment: gah, that is a really round about way to do this!  The pre-edited version is far preferable.