# Why I get additional empty plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas, ipython

I have the following code in my IPython notebook:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.setp(plt.xticks()[1], rotation=45)
plt.figure(figsize=(17, 10)) # <--- This is the problematic line!!!!!!!!!!!!!
plt.plot_date(df['date'],df['x'], color='black', linestyle='-')
plt.plot_date(df['date'],df['y'], color='red', linestyle='-')
plt.plot_date(df['date'],df['z'], color='green', linestyle='-')
```

In the above example `df` is pandas data frame.

Without the marked line (containig `figsize`) the plot is too small. With the mentioned line I have an increased image as I want but before it I have an additional empty plot.

Does anybody know why it happens an how this problem can be resolved?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254379/how-can-i-attach-a-pyplot-function-to-a-figure-instance/14261698#14261698 for a ramble about the state machine vs OO interfaces to mpl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reversing the first two lines after the `import`.  plt.setp is opening a figure.

Answer (score 0):

here's how I would do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17, 10))
plt.setp(plt.xticks()[1], rotation=45)
ax.plot_date(df['date'],df['x'], color='black', linestyle='-')
ax.plot_date(df['date'],df['y'], color='red', linestyle='-')
ax.plot_date(df['date'],df['z'], color='green', linestyle='-')
```

It's a good practice to explicitly create and operate on your your Figure and Axes objects.