# Matplotlib figure doesn't render correctly if show not called

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I'm using matlibplot with Python 2.7.5 :: Anaconda 1.7.0 (64-bit)
The only uncommented lines in my matlibplot.rc file are:

```
figure.figsize   : 10, 5    # figure size in inches
figure.dpi       : 80      # figure dots per inch  
figure.facecolor : 1   # figure facecolor; 0.75 is scalar gray  
savefig.dpi         : 80      # figure dots per inch  
savefig.facecolor   : white    # figure facecolor when saving
```

If I call:

```
plt.savefig(name, bbox_inches=0)  
plt.show()
```

everything works fine

Output from show:
[image]

Output from savefig:
[image]

However, if I simply comment out the show line the same file looks like this:
[image]

What's going on???  How can I fix this?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254379/how-can-i-attach-a-pyplot-function-to-a-figure-instance/14261698#14261698 for an explanation of the state machine vs OO interfaces to mpl.

Comment: and can you post enough code to reproduce this?  The accepted answer may work, but it does not really explain what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that previous figures are being overlaid on the current figure, especially if you have hold on.

Two simple ways to fix this:

Toggle hold before plotting to clear the graph:

```
pylab.hold(False) # clears graph
pylab.hold(True) # restores to state you want
```

Or explicitly clear the graph after saving:

```
pylab.save(...)
pylab.close()
```

The reason you don't see this behaviour with `show` is that there is an implicit `close` called when you close the figure which appears.

Comment: Yup that was it.  Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say `pylab.hold(False)` clears the figure.  That should just toggles a bool in `axes` object.

Comment: Further, you don't call the `close` until _after_ the file as already saved to disk, so I do not understand how that could affect the saved graph.

Comment: @tcaswell - if there is existing data in the figure (due to a previous hold), `hold(False)` will clear it.  Similarly with closing the figure.  The issue was that previous runs of the function had left data on the current figure, which the next `savefig` call then saw.  As you can see, this solved arghdos' problem :)

Comment: no, `hold()` toggles a bool which controls if `clf()` is called the text time you call a plotting function, turning in on and off has no effect.