# matplotlib backend wrongly combines multiple graphs when used on nginx server

Tags: python, django, graph, nginx, matplotlib

I am developing a Django based site that does language processing.  Part of the site is generating Matplotlib graphs from textual data.  I have everything up and running and it works perfectly on my dev server.  When I switch over to nginx for our outward facing test server, the graphs get all crazy. They start merging elements from each graph after I have run one or two graphs.  I have added visual examples below to illustrate what I am talking about.  Has anyone ever seen this before?

Here is a correct version of the first type of plot.

[image]

Here is a correct version of the second type of plot. 
[image]

Now sometimes after I have processed multiple graphs, They start getting wonky and combining different elements of each graph.  Observer how the picture below combines elements from both.

[image]

These graphs are on separate pages with different views and work perfectly on my Django dev server.  This led me to believe that it was something crazy with the backend of Matplotlib, but I have tried out all of the different backends and I get the same result.  Is this Nginx caching things or something? my mind is truly boggled.

Comment: Any possibility the two views are accessing the same memory/plot object somehow, rather than instantiating an entirely new plot object?(Some code could be helpful to look at here.)

Comment: You were super right on there pztrick. I had to go back and use the object oriented API vs the Pylab API.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254379/how-can-i-attach-a-pyplot-function-to-a-figure-instance/14261698#14261698

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the Pylab API for Matplotlib and the two views were somehow accessing the same plot object.  I ended up using the object oriented Matplotlib API.  It is slightly less user friendly, but it allows you to have multiple figure instances running in parallel.  This [article](http://www.packtpub.com/article/advanced-matplotlib-part1) does a great job explaining the difference.