# pcolormesh() different behavior when using OO vs state machine interfaces

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to use the [OO interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14261698/10750537) of matplotlib (3.1.2) to draw some pictures in Python, but I get unpleasant results when calling pcolormesh(). The issue disappears when using the state-machine interface. However, as far as I understand, I cannot use the latter because I need to manage several axes.

Please consider the following example code that shows the issue:

```
import matplotlib   
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np

OO = True #Set to False to make it work 
#
f = 7.5e8 + np.arange(4096) * (1.25e9 - 7.5e8) / 4096
t = np.arange(1024) / 1000
sxx = np.random.rand(f.size,t.size)
#
if OO:
    fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
    axes = matplotlib.pyplot.axes(figure=fig)
    spectrogram = axes.pcolormesh(t, f, sxx, shading='auto')
    fig.colorbar(spectrogram)
else:
    spectrogram = matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh(t, f, sxx, shading='auto')
    matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar(spectrogram)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

The results is poor (e.g, almost no tick along the y-axis), as shown below. Editing the x/y limits or ticks does not fix it.

[image: Glitches]

Nevertheless, if "OO" is set to "False" in the code above, the result is fine (see below)
[image: Ok]

How can I get the OO interface working as the state-machine interface?

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? Btw, a more standard approach would be `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`. I can't recreate this in matplotlib 3.8.1.

Comment: 3.1.2 (reported at the beginning)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue on 3.7.2.

Comment: Testing on another machine with version 3.7.4, I even get "TypeError: add_subplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'figure'". Does the code run on your versions?

Comment: No, which is why I suggested `plt.subplots()`.

Comment: The recommended oo way is via `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` (instead of calling `pyplot.figure()` and `pyplot.axes()`).  `pyplot.axes()` doesn't work well with automatic functionality (such as nicely fitting the labels etc.).  You really should avoid that function.

Comment: For context, subplots and axes used to be different classes, but were merged at matplotlib v3.7 https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/23573.  If there is no exiting axes or subplot, then the `pyplot` method will call `fig.add_subplot` under the hood.

Answer (score -2):

When using the OO (object-oriented) interface, you need to ensure that you set the limits and ticks for both x and y axes explicitly. So add the following lines to set the limits and ticks for both axes:

```
import matplotlib   
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

OO = True  # Set to False to make it work

f = 7.5e8 + np.arange(4096) * (1.25e9 - 7.5e8) / 4096
t = np.arange(1024) / 1000
sxx = np.random.rand(f.size, t.size)

if OO:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()  # Use subplots instead of figure and axes separately
    spectrogram = ax.pcolormesh(t, f, sxx, shading='auto')
    fig.colorbar(spectrogram)

    # Set limits and ticks for both axes
    ax.set_xlim(t.min(), t.max())
    ax.set_ylim(f.min(), f.max())
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(t.min(), t.max(), 5))
    ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(f.min(), f.max(), 5))
else:
    spectrogram = plt.pcolormesh(t, f, sxx, shading='auto')
    plt.colorbar(spectrogram)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If u want to add the label and title add in these code inside loop, both if and else

```
# Add labels and title
    ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    ax.set_title('Spectrogram')
```

Comment: Something must be misunderstood.  `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh` and `axes.pcolormesh` are internally exactly the same function.  The basic error is the call to `matplotlib.pyplot.axes(figure=fig)` which isn't meant for creating subplots (by default it creates a full-window plot).  Further, it is extremely confusing not to shorten `matplotlib.pyplot` to `plt`